# Let $n$ lines be drawn in the plane so that each of them intersects the others but any three lines do not coincide at any point.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

a) Let $n$ lines be drawn in the plane so that each of them intersects the others but any three lines do not coincide at any point. For $n\geq 0$, let $a_n$ be the number of regions into which the plane is separated by these $n$ lines. Find and solve a recurrence relation for $a_n$.

b) For the situation in part a), let $b_n$ be the number of infinite regions obtained that way. Find and solve a recurrence relation for $b_n$.

a) If we look at what happens when we add the nth line, it will intersect with all the other $n-1$ lines, so it will pass through $n$ regions, thus dividing them in two. This means that the number of regions will increase by $n$. Therefore, our recurrence relation is:

\begin{align*}
a_n-a_{n-1}=n,\ n>0,\ a_0=1.
\end{align*}

We solve it this way in a simple way:

\begin{align*}
a_n=a_{n-1}+n=a_{n-2}+(n-1)=a_0+1+2+a_{n-2}+(n-1)=a_0+1+2+a_0+1+2+\dots +n.
\end{align*}

Therefore, we have:

\begin{align*}
a_n=\frac{n^2+n+2}{2},n\geq 0.
\end{align*}

b) Let $b_n =$ be the number of infinite regions resulting in $n$ such lines. When the nth line is drawn it is divided into $n$ segments. The first and the nth segment each create a new infinite region. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
b_n=b_{n-1}+2,\ n>1,\ b_1=2
\end{align*}

I don't know if this is correct for a), since for example

[image]

By adding the red line, it fulfills the given conditions, but does not divide all regions in two.

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/LinesDividePlane.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to (a) is correct.  This is called the [Lazy Caterer's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence), and is one more than the triangle numbers

Your answer to (b) is also correct for $n\ge 1$ and could be written as $b_n=2n$.  In effect there are $n$ lines so $2n$ rays coming out of the area separating $2n$ infinite areas

Your diagram shows $6$ areas ($5$ on the boundary) from $3$ cuts and $10$ ($7$ on the boundary) from $4$ cuts, but you should have $7$ ($6$) and $11$ ($8$). The missing area should be in the top middle, and would appear if you were to move the top middle intersection slightly below the boundary